# Flatpickr - how to set format of alt input after date update

Tags: flatpickr

If I am updating a field with a date, how do I get the alt view to display the correct format. For example this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohj1ca2r/):

```
<input class="flatpickr" id="dateInput" type="text">
<button onclick="updateDate()">Update</button>

<script>
  flatpickr(".flatpickr", {
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "j F Y",
    defaultDate: "2022-10-20"
  });

  function updateDate() {
    var e=document.getElementById("dateInput");
    e.value="2023-05-01";
  }
</script>
```

The date value is changed but the alt display not updated. I have tried a number of things:

```
e._flatpickr.altInput.value="2023-01-05"; // Sets the value but not the format
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flatpickr `setDate` method for this.

**Documentation:** https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/#setdatedate-triggerchange-datestrformat

```js
let dateInput = flatpickr(".flatpickr", {
  altInput: true,
  altFormat: "j F Y",
  defaultDate: "2022-10-20",
});

function updateDate() {
  dateInput.setDate(new Date("2023-01-01"));
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.13/flatpickr.min.js"></script>

<input class="flatpickr" id="dateInput" type="text">
<button onclick="updateDate()">Update</button>
```